# My network only predicts one class

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to do a six-class classification using CNNs. The first problem I have is that the validation loss and accuracy start high. It seems that until it reaches a lower value neither training, not validation accuracy is calculated since it is stuck in the same value

[image: (training start)].

Then, when it does start calculating the accuracy it goes terribly bad:

[image: half training]. I am using the following net:

```python
inp = Input(shape=input_shape)
out = Conv2D(16, (5, 5),activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(inp)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)

out = Conv2D(32, (3, 3),activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)

out = Conv2D(32, (3, 3),activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)

out = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = Conv2D(64, (3, 3),activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)

out = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = Conv2D(128, (3, 3),activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Flatten()(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
dense1 = Dense(6, activation="softmax")(out)
model = Model(inputs = inp, outputs = dense1)
```

I have checked that the labels are correct, and the images are fine as well. The network's ouput is always the same class (which by the way is the class with fewer images).

I am using Adam optimizer with `lr = 1e-5`

Comment: You have used so much of regularization that the network have failed to learn anything. Remove all the kernel regularizers. Also, remove dropout from the conv blocks as of now. Start training and if you see overfitting, then start with dropout in conv blocks

Answer (score 2):

the code seems fine for 6 class classification. But, I think your network have too many dropout layer. And most of the signal don't reach to end. Have you tried a simpler network on your dataset?

Try this for first approach to training:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py